# One class implementing multiple interfaces using dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I don't have any code  with me to show you guys, but all I need to know that does Dependency Injection work in a scenario where a class implements multiple interfaces.

I do know about a single interface implemented by multiple classes using Dependency Injection.

Comment: What do you mean by work for classes with multiple interfaces?  Do you merely want to register and retrieve instances of a class regardless of whether it implements two interfaces or not?

Comment: ya thats what I wanna do register and retrieve instances of class and get the concrete implementation of those interfaces which this class inherits.

Comment: Ok, then I agree with John's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Why wouldn't it? As long as the class implements the interface you need you shouldn't have to care what else the class happens to implement.